# Integral of $\int \frac{x^2+5x-3}{x+2}dx$ using integration by parts?

Tags: calculus

Does anyone know how I might solve this integral using integration by parts? Thanks!
$$
\int \frac{x^2+5x-3}{x+2}dx
$$

Comment: Is it necessary to use by parts? You can simply separate out into partial fractions and integrate.

Comment: Please show us your own attempts to solve your question next time.  You'd find problem-statement questions poorly received here in general.

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$\int \frac{x^2+5x-3}{x+2}dx=\int\frac{(x+2)(x+3)-9}{x+2}dx=\int(x+3)dx-9\int\frac{1}{x+2}dx$$
$$=\frac{x^2}{2}+3x-9\ln(x+2)+C.$$